# How to invoke class constructor, if class and object is in the same file

Tags: scala, maven, companion-object

In `MyFactory.scala`, object and Class defined in the same file with same name, like this

```
package com.mydomain.app.module

object MyFactory{
    val a1 = "a1"
    val b1 = "b1"
}

class MyFactory(config:Configuration){
    //blah....
}
```

Problem is I cannot Initiate MyFactory object in another class

```
var myFactory = new Myfactory(defaultConfiguration)
```

due to the error

```
not found: type MyFactory
```

All I did was a common import

```
import com.mydomain.app.module.MyFactory
```

What is the valid way to initiate an object of the class, if I can't modify anything from `MyFactory.scala` (legacy code)

Comment: Try `import com.mydomain.app.module._`

Comment: @jwvh thanks, now previous error is gone but now it complains about `object app is not a member of package com.mydomain`

Comment: @Dreamer Is `Myfactory` actually `MyFactory`? Regarding "is not a member" error do `sbt clean compile`.

Comment: @Dmytro Mitin Yes it is. Well the Scala application is not build on sbt, just a maven project.

Comment: @Dreamer Then mvn clean compile

Comment: @jwvh When you do `import com.mydomain.app.module.MyFactory` you import both companions (class and object).

Comment: @Dreamer "object app is not a member of package com.mydomain" can mean that you're trying to recompile `MyFactory.scala` referring to something not compiled in `com.mydomain...` Recompile the whole project.

Comment: @Dmytro Mitin thanks, however required `com.mydomain`. packages and classes are from maven dependency / jar files which were already compiled

Comment: @Dreamer did you do clean compile of your project? Importing `com.mydomain.app.module.MyFactory` is enough for importing both companions. Try to create minimal project with the same issue. You seem to have some issues with building your project.

Comment: Dmytro Mitin Thanks, yea seems the issue has out of the scope of this question. So could you or @jwvh please make an answer so I will close this question.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
var myFactory = new MyFactory(defaultConfiguration)
```

is the valid way to initiate an object of the class.

`import com.mydomain.app.module.MyFactory` should be enough for bringing `MyFactory` (and its companion) to the scope.

Sometimes "object `app` is not a member of package `com.mydomain`" can mean that you're trying to recompile `MyFactory.scala` referring to something not compiled in `com.mydomain...`

Try `mvn clean compile`.